# Hummus-recipe NPM: TypeError: Unable to start parsing PDF file

Tags: javascript, node.js, hummus.js

```
const HummusRecipe = require('hummus-recipe');
const pdfDoc = new HummusRecipe(inputFilePath, outputFilePath);
```

Above code will raise error **TypeError: Unable to start parsing PDF file** in hummus-recipe library if the input PDF is in invalid standard PDF Format.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I've created a solution to deal with this error in **hummus-recipe**
It's caused due to invalid PDF Format that's not acceptable by **hummus-recipe**.

```
exports.PDFConversionToHummusFormat = async (inputPath, outputPath) => {
const { PDFDocument } = require('pdf-lib');
const HummusRecipe = require('hummus-recipe');
const fileBytes = fs.readFileSync(inputPath);
const convertedPdf = await PDFDocument.load(fileBytes);
const pdfBytes = await convertedPdf.save();
fs.writeFileSync(inputPath, pdfBytes);
const pdfDoc = new HummusRecipe(inputPath, outputPath);
return pdfDoc;
};


const HummusRecipe = require('hummus-recipe');
let pdfDoc;
try {
        pdfDoc = new HummusRecipe(inputPath, outputPath);
} catch (error) {
  if (error.message === 'TypeError: Unable to start parsing PDF file') {
        pdfDoc = await PDFConversionToHummusFormat(inputPath, outputPath);
  } else {
      console.error('Error in Hummus Recipe Library ->', error);
  }
}
```

Note: You can check if your PDF is valid or not at **https://www.pdfen.com/pdf-a-validator** OR You can convert your PDF to a valid version at **https://docupub.com/pdfconvert/**